# Fonts Not Displaying on Mobile/iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, browser

I am going to go crazy. I am trying to use Agency FB and Calibri fonts on my website which seem to work on all browsers whilst on Desktop but they do not display when I go to my site on my iPhone - some other standard font is used.

I have used Agency FB for my logo and for a font within a Vector I created in XD. Both of the text contained within these are part of the vector. The body of my website also uses various Calibri weights and styles. The problem being that the font is replaced for my logo and the vector image which completley destroys the layout as the font just doesn't fit.

I have used font-face in my css stylesheet but that does not seem to be working. I have included the code for font-face below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri Light';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri Light Italic';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Agency FB';
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot');
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri Bold';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri Italic';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Agency FB Bold';
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.svg#AgencyFB-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm aware .tff files are used for iPhone/Safari but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: all font family same name `font-family: 'Calibri';`

Comment: Why are you using the same `font-family` in different places? e.g. `font-family: 'Calibri';`. Each `font-family` should have a different name.

Answer (score 0):

try with a different `font-family` name like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriLight';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Light.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriLightItalic';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-LightItalic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Agency FB Reg';
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot');
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriBold';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriItalic';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Calibri-Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Agency FB Bold';
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/AgencyFB-Bold.svg#AgencyFB-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I tried this (see updated code) but still not working on iOS safari or chrome

Comment: Any resolution here? I cannot make the Calibri font work on ios either.